# Python scraping with requests module - how can i optimize my code?

Tags: python, optimization, python-requests

I've made discord bot that checks subreddit where people post links with free games, when someone posts link (epicgames, steam), bot detects it and starts to scrape given url, but i don't know if i am doing it most optimized way, bot gathers source code from website and cuts it:

```
source = requests.get(URL).text
position = source.find('"mainEntityOfPage":true,"name":"')
source = source[position + 32:]
position = source.find('"')
title_of_game = source[:position]
```

For every string i cut it like above. I've seen that a lot of people use Beautiful soup, should i change module or optimize it more?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You can also use the [api](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-the-reddit-api-in-python-5e05ddfd1e5c)

Comment: I am using praw to get post description(links to free game), then i use requests to scrap link(epicgames, steam, gog websites)

Comment: do whatever you like. Your code may work faster then`BeautifulSoup` because it doesn't have parse HTML - but I don't know if you will difference in time. `BeautifulSoup` can be useful when you have to search more complex element. But it seems you search inside JavaScript code - and `BeautifulSoup` can't search inside `JavaScript`. `JavaScript` sometimes keep data as JSON string and then module `JSON` can be useful.